# Using IPMI in virtualization - what is the difference betweem virtualbmc project of openstack and QEMU device ipmi-bmc-sim?

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, kvm, libvirt, ipmi

I'm setting up a virtual lab on my laptop (using kvm/qemu), and need an IPMI solution (e.g., to use STONITH as is etc.).

I have looked at [virtualBMC](https://docs.openstack.org/developer/tripleo-docs/environments/virtualbmc.html) and [QEMU ipmi-bmc-sim](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/invocation.html) (search for ipmi on the page)

I have not tried either yet, but from reading documentation it would appear virtualBMC is using a BMC server  to register all the VMs, while the QEMU approach is more integrated to the VM itself.

1. Is my understanding correct?
2. Which method is preferable for a home lab? Or are they meant to be used together?
3. Any experience or recommendations in setting up VMs using IPMI/BMC ?

I'm not interested in researching or developing BMC. I just need to simulate cluster behavior which on physical nodes relies on IPMI, so I would prefer a simpler solution that "just works" to a more correct or flexible solution with more bells and whistles. I only require power on/off/reset capabilities, without sel/sdr/sensors/...